# Angular kendoGrid datatem pass null to backend

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

I'm trying to implement `add` feature in my project. 
I did some research, but to no avail.

I did these steps:

1. I made a `component.html` with kendoGrid

```html
<base href="/">
<br />
<div class="form-group">
  <label>List of books</label>
</div>
<!--<ng-template #readOnlyTemplate let-books>-->
<kendo-grid [data]="books"
            [height]="420"
            (edit)="editHandler($event)" (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)"
            (save)="saveHandler($event)" (remove)="removeHandler($event)"
            (add)="addHandler($event)"
            [navigable]="true"
            (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)"
            [kendoGridReactiveEditing]="createFormGroup">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button kendoGridAddCommand type="button">Add new</button>
  </ng-template>
  <kendo-grid-column field="genreID" title="Genre" width="70">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="books">
      <input [(ngModel)]="books.genreID" kendoGridFocusable name="genreID" class="k-textbox" type="number" required />
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="bookName" title="Name" width="120">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="books">
      <input [(ngModel)]="books.bookName" kendoGridFocusable name="bookName" class="k-textbox" required />
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="yearOfPublish" title="Year">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="books">
      <input [(ngModel)]="books.yearOfPublish" kendoGridFocusable name="yearOfPublish" class="k-textbox" type="number" min="876" max="2018" required />
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-command-column title="Action" width="220">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-isNew="isNew">
      <button kendoGridEditCommand type="button" [primary]="true">Edit</button>
      <button kendoGridRemoveCommand type="button">Remove</button>
      <button kendoGridSaveCommand type="button">
        {{ isNew ? 'Save' : 'Update' }}
      </button>
      <button kendoGridCancelCommand type="button">{{ isNew ? 'Discard changes' : 'Cancel' }}</button>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-command-column>

</kendo-grid>

<br />
```

2. I made a `component.ts` with `add` logic

```js
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {

  public books: Book[] = [];

  private editedRowIndex: number;
  private book: Book;

  public formGroup: FormGroup;

  public gridState: State = {
    sort: [],
    skip: 0,
    take: 10
  };

  constructor(private dataService: DataBookService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createFormGroup = this.createFormGroup.bind(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.load();
  }

  public onStateChange(state: State) {
    this.gridState = state;
    debugger;

    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.dataService.getBooks().subscribe(data => {
      this.books = data;
    });
    console.log("Startup entity must be here");

  }

  addHandler({ sender}) {
    sender.addRow(this.createFormGroup(new Book()))
  }

  public saveHandler({ sender, rowIndex, dataItem, isNew }) {
    if (isNew) {

      dataItem = this.formGroup.value;

      this.dataService.save(dataItem, isNew);
     
      sender.closeRow(rowIndex);
    }
    if (!isNew) {
      this.dataService.updateBook(dataItem);
        
      sender.closeRow(rowIndex);
    }

  }

  public createFormGroup(args: any): any {
    const item = args.isNew ? new Book() : args.dataItem;
    //debugger;
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      //'BookID': item.bookID,
      'bookName': [item.bookName, Validators.required],
      'genreID': item.genreID,
      'yearOfPublish': [item.yearOfPublish, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,3}')])]
    });

    return this.formGroup;
  }
}
```

3. Send results of component work to the service, which sends it to ASP.NET Core Controller:

```js
export class DataBookService extends BehaviorSubject<any[]> {
  private url = 'http://localhost:49403/api/Book';

  private data: any[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super([]);
  }

  getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    var result = this.http.get<Book[]>(this.url + '/getAll');
    return result;
  }
  getBook<Book>(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/get' + id);
  }
  createBook<Book>(book: Book): Observable<Book> {
    return this.http.post<Book>(this.url + "/create", book).toPromise();
  }
  public save(data: Book, isNew?: boolean) {

    if (isNew) {
      this.createBook(data);
    }
    if (!isNew) {
      this.updateBook(data);
      console.log("updated");
    }
    this.reset();
  }
  private reset() {
    this.data = [];
  }
```

The problem is that I have an empty `dataItem` from `component.html` and I have no idea why?
[image]

**EDIT**

As i'm using a reactiveEditing forms and trying to create a form when i press 'Add', createFormGroup(args) funct says that

**Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'Book'.
Property 'bookID' is missing in type 'FormGroup'.**

Why could it be?

**EDIT 2**

I found that info from my inputs contains in _currentView in core.js, here is a scrinshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuD6r.png)

Comment: if i am understanding your problem correctly, you are saying `this.formGroup.value;` is returning null?

Comment: Yes, both this.formGroup.value; and dataItem. I put a screenshot of TS debug at the end of my question.

Comment: not sure if this will fix your issue, but have you tried `[formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)"` on your edit template input?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm trying to put it inside my input, like that :
 <input [(ngModel)]="books.genreID" [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)" name="genreID" class="k-textbox" type="number" required />
but got an error :

**Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("le="Genre" width="70">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="books" >
      <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="books.genreID" [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)" name="genreID" class="k-textb"): ng:///AppModule/BookListComponent.html@19:13**

Comment: You don't need ngmodel if you use form control

Comment: Okay, I've added your peace of code, and now its create only one field in the table, and throw errors on another:


**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined**

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand properly your sample, and now i use it like like **[formControl]="formGroup.get(books.bookName)"** and now it throws:

**ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute**

Comment: I rejected h idea of reactive forms and implemented data manipulating in in-cell directive style. thanks everyone for attention. 
Link with examples: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-directives/